# Iterating through an ArrayList and also dynamically removing and adding elements at a specific index

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, nlp

I'm trying to find an answer to my question but nothing seems to be specific but if this is a duplicate, I apologize (also I'm new to java).

So say that I have an ArrayList that contains:

```
[I, love, computer, science, and, applied, mathematics]
```

and I would like to change the array so that

```
[I, love, computer science, and, applied mathematics]
```

Basically, I would like to remove "computer" and "science" and insert "computer science" at that specific location. Then the iterator must keep going from "and" and do the same for "applied" and "mathematics".

I was thinking about using a forloop with indexing i, but I'm learning that dynamically removing from the list without the use of an iterator is bad. I could also use a LinkedList but I'm not sure how the indexes would change.

I would really appreciate some suggestions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if those objects in the list are strings then no need to do a for loop over the collection, just `remove` them add the new element

```
List<String> xyzList = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList("I", "love", "computer", "science", "and", "applied", "mathematics"));
System.out.println(xyzList);
int index = xyzList.indexOf("computer");
xyzList.remove("computer");
xyzList.remove("science");
xyzList.add(index, "computer science");
System.out.println(xyzList);
```

but hey... be careful  and think about what is going to happen is those elements are not in the list.... :)

Comment: hmmm...perhaps I should clarify - I wouldn't really know what's in this arraylist to be more specific. I would be iterating through to see if three indexes combined would make an actual word and if it does, delete those 3 strings from those indexes, insert new word, and keep moving down the list